# Titanium app not running when move from 3.1.3 GA to 3.5.0 GA in iOS

Tags: ios

I have built app using SDK 3.1.3 GA for Titanium in iOS. I have completed App and generated .ipa file 
but i am not able to upload it on iTunes as iOS has made 64 bit compatibility compulsory which is not present in the SDK 3.1.3 GA that i am using. On further research i have found that, i have to 
 use new titanium SDK i.e. 3.5.0 GA for building 64 bit app. After that i have downloaded new titanium studio with SDK 3.5.0 and move my app from old titanium(SDK 3.1.3 GA) to 
new titanium(SDK 3.5.0). But when i try to run the App in new titanium, it gives error regarding missing files in Ti.FileSystem.applicationDataDirectory. I have checked path to applicationDataDirectory 
and it is different in old titanium and new titanium. Is there any solution to applicationDataDirectory error?

Comment: Please also mention what things you have already tried.